# Pandas time series resample

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame with a datetime stamp column and a value column

```
datetime                 value
-------------------------------
2014-02-21 17:16:42        1
2014-02-21 17:46:00        2
2014-02-21 19:06:03        2
2014-02-22 03:16:42        4
```

and I'd like to replace the datetime column with a different datetime column that has additional values in it, and obtain something like this

```
datetime                 value
-------------------------------
2014-02-21 17:16:42        1
2014-02-21 17:20:00       
2014-02-21 17:46:00        2
2014-02-21 19:06:03        2
2014-02-22 00:06:42       
2014-02-22 03:16:42        4
```

(Maybe with NaN or something similar in the empty value positions)

I know this isn't resampling, but I didn't know what to call it. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can reindex if you have the desired index. Do you have that? where do the new datetimes come from?

Comment: I have a list of the new datetimes, but I'm not sure I see how to reindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
df = df[new_index]
```

Sweet, eah?

Values in `new_index` which do not appear in `df.index` will get a `NaN` value.